# The output method is in an endless loop

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.*;
public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        int x = getRandomNumber();
        int v = 0;
        int y = getGuessFromUser();
        output(x,y);
    }
    public static int getRandomNumber() {
        return (int)(Math.random()*25)+1;
    }
    public static int getGuessFromUser() {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int y;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 25: ");
            y = keyboard.nextInt();

        } while(y <= 0 || y > 25);

        return y;
    }
    public static void output( int x, int y ) 
    {
        int v = 0;

        do {

            if(x > y) 
                System.out.println("TOO LOW");
            if(x < y) 
                System.out.println("TOO HIGH");

        } while( x != y );

        do {
            v++;
            System.out.print("YOU ARE CORRECT! IT TOOK YOU " + v + " GUESSES!");
        } while( x == y );
    }
}
```

> The loop won't end when someone guesses a number.
>   I need the loop to output TOO HIGH, TOO LOW or CORRECT and then ask the user to guess again.
>   Instead, it goes into a continuous loop.

Comment: you do not change y in the loop. Call guess in the loop body.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416030/issue-with-do-while-loop?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

```
 do{

    if(x > y)
       System.out.println("TOO LOW");
    if(x < y)
      System.out.println("TOO HIGH");

}while(x!=y);
```

No where in the loop are you updating x or y so it will always run if it enters the loops.

Instead, two possibilities are either have output return a boolean based on whether the guess was correct and loop on that or update the variables in the loops in output.